# Model Validation and catching the errors in form Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to write model validation in the model class not in the ModelForm in order to DRY.

I managed to do this, but when I raise the `ValidationError` wether it's `django.forms.ValidationError` or `django.core.exception.ValidationError` it will break the page.

How to show the error message without breaking the page.

Comment: What do you mean by breaking the page? HTTP 500 error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the validation of the model is done on save, so if you have something like this in your view

```
if form.is_valid():
    obj = form.save()
```

Change it into something like;

```
if form.is_valid():
    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    try:
        obj.save()
    except ValidationError as e:
        # i.e. Add error message from e to form
        pass
    else:
        return http.HttpResponseRedirect('.')
```

Comment: This is not true. Model save does not call model validation: it is called by the usual form.is_valid() if the form is a ModelForm.

Comment: Apparently I was wrong, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#validation-on-a-modelform says so. But answer appeared to be right by Emad, so maybe adding form.is_valid was enough Emad?

Comment: @daniel you are right, but I'm override the model save function and force the validation

Comment: @Blackeagle52's link is dead now. We can instead check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#validation-on-a-modelform).